# Odd jquery behaviour when moving text between fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textboxes, the first has an id of storytxt and the second textbox is dynamically generated in js.

In the second textbox I am setting the value like so

```
value=" + $('#storytxt').val() + "
```

When I type into #storytxt text box, and I run the script all works great until I use any white space. The outputs are:

Single words:

```
<input class="story" id="q1" type="text" value="Test">
```

Multiple words:

```
<input class="story" id="q3" type="text" value="Test" this="">
```

Desired outcome:

```
<input class="story" id="q3" type="text" value="Test this">
```

I can't workout why jquery is parsing the text the way it is, unless .val on a text object doesn't like whitespace or is it an encoding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a jQuery issue. HTML attributes must be quoted to preserve spaces; you must account for this when building the HTML string.

```js
"value='" + $('#storytxt').val() + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd not spotted it :(... the final code was value='" + $('#storytxt').val() + "'